# iPhoto does not open a window after Lion Upgrade

Tags: macos, photos.app

iPhoto is not properly anymore since I upgraded on Lion. It starts and seems to be alive in Task Switcher or in the Menu Bar, but there is no open Window for iPhoto.

I re-installed from the AppStore several times, (after deleting it), but I can not open a iPhotoLibrary.

This is the console output:

```
24.07.11 14:48:12.874 iPhoto: *** NSMapInsert(): attempt to insert notAKeyMarker
24.07.11 14:48:15.000 kernel: (default pager): [KERNEL]: ps_select_segment - send HI_WAT_ALERT
24.07.11 14:48:15.000 kernel: macx_swapon SUCCESS
```

Any idea what I could do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iLife(iPhoto is part of iLife)does not come with Lion you have to download it separately, make sure it's installed XD

Comment: Do you think re-installing iLife (from the DVD) makes a difference compared to re-isntalling just iPhoto from the App Store?

Comment: I think you can install iLife from the DVD & then it will probably update to be compatible with 10.7. I haven't tried it myself but it worked with iWork so I don't see why it shouldn't work with iLife. I recommend trying to install from the DVD first before buying the app from the App Store

Comment: Thank  you very much. I deleted iPhoto, iMovie and GarageBand, deleted all iPhoto-related files and folders in /.ibrary and <user>/Library and re-installed from the CD!

Answer (score 1):

Just find and move to the trash the next file (preferences of iPhoto)
`/Users/youracount/Library/com.apple.iPhoto.plist`

then, open iPhoto.

Works for me.